# Calendar import - new events inserted by date messes up other columns of data

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar

This Code is the only one that works to input my shared google calendar into a sheet. I use a master Calendar for all appointments in my medical office. Calendar data comes in 4 columns Columns B, C, D, E (from the calendar (start time, location, description, Title).  I have added Columns F - O with additional data such as 'no show', time of arrival, rescheduled for another day and formulas that calculate the number of days between appointments.
When the calendar events update from the calendar to the sheet, my added columns of F-O no longer match the row of data.  For example, my entered data of 'no show' for that appointment will be in the cell above where it should be. How do I fix this so that new rows of data are added to the bottom of the sheet and stay there so that I don't have mixed up data?

```
function importCalendar(){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Calendar Import'); 
  var calendarName = sheet.getRange('C2').getValue(); 
  var start = sheet.getRange('C3').getValue(); 
  var end = sheet.getRange('C4').getValue(); 
   
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarName); 
  if(calendar) {var calendarId = calendar.getId();} 
  if(!calendar) { 
    var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0]; 
    var calendarId = calendarName; 
  } 
   
  var events = calendar.getEvents(start, end); 
  var eventDetails = []; 
  for(var i = 0; i<events.length; i++){ 
    eventDetails.push([events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation()]); 
  } 
   
  //write calendar details to spreadsheet 
  var startRow = 8; 
  var startCol = 2;  
  for(var j = 0; j<eventDetails.length; j++){ 
    var tempRange = sheet.getRange(startRow+j, startCol, 1, 4); 
    var eventArray = new Array(eventDetails[j]); 
    tempRange.setValues(eventArray); 
  } 
  return eventDetails; 
}
```

Comment: Why is `startRow` 8?

Comment: Rows 1-6 are intentionally blank and row 7 contains my headers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is just, "*How do I fix this so that new rows of data are added to the bottom of the sheet...?*"

Right now, you've defined `startRow = 8`, meaning that you're always going to start printing from that row and overwriting whatever is there. Instead, you could try using the [`getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) method, which returns the position of the last row *that has content*.

```
var startRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; // Start one after the last row
```

There is a best practice to [use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations). It's not always appropriate, but I think it may be in your case. If you had 5 events to print, right now you'd call `getRange()` and `setValues()` 5 times, but you can very easily update your code to call those only once for printing.

Alternatively, you could use [`appendRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents), but since you're not printing in column A and it's not a batch operation, I don't think it would be the best approach.